# Disable xemacs modes and highlighting

Tags: emacs, syntax-highlighting, mode

How can i disable all the modes in XEmacs that change the appearance or behaviour of my text files?

All i want from XEmacs is to just show the text and make changes according to my keyboard input and nothing more:

- no auto indentation
- no colored characters, just black on white
- no other font, just the one i selected (e.g. no bold characters when opening a HTML file)

One approach (at least partly) would be to make XEmacs always use fundamental mode, but i don't know how to do that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont have Xemacs, but in gnu emacs putting this in your `~/.emacs`
file goes some way towards this goal:

```
(setq font-lock-global-modes nil
      interpreter-mode-alist nil
      auto-mode-alist nil
      magic-mode-alist nil)
```

Comment: Great, thank you, thank you!
BTW, in xemacs, it goes to ~/.xemacs/custom.el